# How do I preserve my SHA-1 fingerprint keystore certificate?

Tags: android, keystore, sha1

I know how to get my SHA-1 fingerprint either through terminal or eclipse (go to: Window->Preferences->Android->Build), but there has been not many answers on how to keep the SHA-1 fingerprint in cases of emergencies.

Eg, my hard disk died, and I had to export my .apk under a different SHA-1 fingerprint and hence under a complete app new listing in Google Play store.

In case of another harddisk breakdown or a new computer, is there a way to still use the same SHA-1 fingerprint? Maybe I am lacking some knowledge of how keystore certificate works and hopefully someone can enlighten me.

Comment: All you need to do is preserve your keystore file.

Comment: So now I understood what's a keystore file.. better to have it on a cloud then..

Comment: As long as you can trust your cloud, yes. I wouldn't put my keystore files on any service without an SLA and strong privacy policy. BTSync is an option, dropbox, to me, is not.

Answer (score -1):

If your concern is about app store apk file then you have to preserve keystore file with which you have uploaded apk on to play store.Don't worry about SHA-1 fingerprint in any case you have to preserve only keystore. And apk creation is dependent on keystore after you have created it.